Biblical Prophets Who Knew That Their Messages Would Go Unheeded
I would like to know of instances in the Bible where prophets knew beforehand that their messages would go unheeded. Thank you.

Hi DDS, it looks like you've been on the stack for a while, so you should be very familiar with the basics of the Site Scope. Questions which are searching for a text or asking an inquiry without a text are generally Off Topic.

The only one that comes to mind is Micaiah the son of Imlah (1 Kings ch22), who was summoned to Ahab's public consultation of the prophets, an event which was really a propaganda exercise. He was even warned in advance that he was expected to give a favourable answer (v13). So confident was he that neither the king nor anybody else would be listening, that he indulged himself in a little sarcastic compliance (v15) before he gave his real answer (v17).
Just possibly the associated king Jehoshaphat might have paid more attention, but Jehoshaphat chose to fulfil his obligations regardless. In any case, Micaiah does not seem to have been warned that Jehoshapat would be there.
I think most of the other prophets were expecting at least a small minority to listen to them.

Hi Stephen, we need experienced users such as yourself to Vote to Close questions that are Off Topic.
